# Using ArcPy how do you get out a specific category from a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5

I am using ArcPy and wanting to know is there a way to extract a specific category from a shapefile. For example I have a shapefile that I was given that is labled Kansas_pointOfInterest.shp, and I suppose to extract from that only churches (pts I suppose) from that shapefile.

How is this done through ArcPy?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: @smiller ArcMap/ArcGis 10.5

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stackexchange! Please [take the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Some helpful things to include in your post are what you've tried already, example snippets of your code, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways I typically start my code are:

1. Search for the particular tool/method from ArcGIS in Google. Esri has a good set of example codes. e.g. "select layer by attribute arcpy 10.5" led me to [this help document for Select by Attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm)
2. Search for the tool / process in GIS StackExchange - we have a number of posts already related to this.
3. Create a Model within Model Builder and export the code to Python (unfortunately doesn't work this way in ArcGIS Pro)

This may depend on your data and whether you need to loop through several different options, but the basic thing you're trying to do is to Select features from your shapefile by Attribute, and then export the results to a new layer.

Below is the example from Esri. Let us know if you get stuck and what you're running into as an issue.

```
# Name: ExtactFeaturesByLocationAndAttribute.py
# Description: Extract features to a new feature class based on a spatial 
relationships to another layer AND an attribute query

# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the workspace
env.workspace = "c:/data/mexico.gdb"

# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("cities", "lyr") 

# Select all cities which overlap the chihuahua polygon
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "intersect", "chihuahua", 0, 
"new_selection")

# Within selected features, further select only those cities which have a 
population > 10,000   
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", ' 
"population" > 10000 ')

# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", "chihuahua_10000plus")
```

Comment: Thanks. I opened up ArcMap and I narrowed down where it's at. New to arcmap but pretty much found it like this, went to ArcMap, then opened up my shapefile, then went to Selection>Select By Attributes>Under method there was two things "FID" and "category" I selected "category" and found there was like a list of things there. Not sure how to access something like 'ClothingStore' through python code. Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/qsJXeTr

Comment: Within The Select by Attributes dialog box (your screenshot), you would simply click the = then double-click "ClothingStore". In terms of code, it would be something like `categorytosearch = "ClothingStore"` `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr",  "NEW_SELECTION",  '"category" = ' + "'%s'" % categorytosearch`

Comment: Thank you. Another thing I am trying to figure out is after I get that category of ClothingStore and isolate those pts. I want to compare it to another set of pts (churches.shp). So essentially I want to find how many churches are within a 500 meter radius of ClothingStore pts. Is there any arcpy methods that can do this? Thanks once more.

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question. (Also, please clarify why you're trying to utilze arcpy methods as that may help us understand how to help improve your code.)